# BTSTask AddResource Fails Even with Shared Assemblies in GAC

Tags: command-line, biztalk, gac, biztalk2006r2

I am trying to create a BizTalk application (`App1`) and add resources using the `BTSTask` command line utility. Some of the `App1` BizTalk assemblies depend on a few `SharedApp` BizTalk assemblies. I added the `SharedApp` assemblies to the GAC using `gacutil` and verified they were present in the GAC. When I run `BTSTask AddResource`, the command fails for any `App1` BizTalk assembly that depends on any of the `SharedApp` assemblies.

The error message tells me a specific `SharedApp` dll cannot be found for reference. I have verified the details (name, version, etc.) on the `SharedApp` assembly are correct; it is the correct assembly and is present in the GAC.

Shouldn't BizTalk be able to detect those `SharedApp` assemblies in the GAC and allow them to be used as reference assemblies when I call `AddResource`?

Any thoughts on why adding the `SharedApp` assemblies to the GAC did not solve my problem?

**EDIT: Adding command line example text**

```
BTSTask.exe AddApp -ApplicationName:App1 -Server:BTServer1 -Database:BTDatabase1 -Description:App1_instance
BTSTask.exe AddResource -ApplicationName:App1 -Source:"path_to_App1.Assembly.dll" -Destination:"destination_path_for_App1.Assembly.dll" -Type:BizTalkAssembly -Options:GacOnAdd,GacOnInstall -Overwrite -Server:BTServer1 -Database:BTDatabase1
```

Comment: Are the 'SharedApp' assemblies .NET assemblies, or biztalk assemblies?  Also, can you post your script?

Comment: The `SharedApp` assemblies are BizTalk assemblies, as noted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spelunking into our automation and enabling detailed logs, I was able to get a clearer error message:

```
Error: Assembly "App1.Assembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxx" references the following assemblies that must be deployed before deploying this assembly: Assembly "SharedApp.Services, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy"
```

After an online search for that error, I uncovered the following from [a discussion post](http://www.windows-server-answers.com/microsoft/BizTalk/30337132/assembly-x-references-the-following-assemblies-that-must-be.aspx):

> If [a] DLL contains XSD (BizTalk) schemas it must also be deployed to
>   the BizTalk management database.

Apparently, this must be done in addition to adding the assemblies to the GAC. This is the reason why adding `App1` assemblies to my application would fail; although I added the `SharedApp` BizTalk assemblies to the GAC, they were also needed in the BizTalk management database.

Thank you to those who took a look at this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is this BizTalk 2010?  In that case, it might be something to do with the 'dual cache' that was introduced with .NET 4.0.
As you might know, there are now 2 global assembly caches and assemblies from the 2.0 GAC cannot use 4.0 GAC assemblies.
So maybe your SharedApp is in the .NET4.0 cache and the resource you want to add is compiled against an older version of BizTalk?

Just thinking out loud, you never know if it helps.
Cheers

Comment: This is BizTalk 2006, using .NET 2.0, so no issues with the 4.0 GAC.

Comment: Sorry, seems to be something else then.  One thing I remember from the past was that there were files in a system folder somewhere (like a hidden GAC) that contained older versions of dlls from me and these were being used instead of the real GAC'ed ones.  It's probably nothing, but maybe do a dir /s on your c-drive to search for your dlls and see if you have items that should not be there.